# How to get a custom error status with RTK Query

Tags: redux, rtk-query

Our backend returns something like this for success:

```js
{
      message: "Entry Succesfully Entered",
      errorCode: 0,
      data: {
        success: true,
      },
      info: [],
    });
  }
```

And something like this for failure:

```js
{
    info: [],
    message: "Some info about the error",
    errorCode: 
}
```

The actual error code in the failure response is basically meaningless.

I've got my mutation transforming the response thusly:

```js
transformResponse: ({ data, errorCode, message }) => {
  if (data?.success) return { success: true };

  return {
    error: {
      status: errorCode,
      message,
    },
  };
},
```

However this is always delivered in the `data` member of the result returned by the RTKQ hook.

Is there a way to affect the `error` (and possibly the `isError`) part of that returned result?

Comment: The only thing you could do there is wrapping the `baseQuery` to handle that and return an `{ error: .... }` object in that case.

Comment: @phry can you elaborate in detail?

Comment: There are multiple examples of wrapping baseQuery in the docs. [For example this](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage/customizing-queries#adding-meta-information-to-queries). baseQuery is just a function that either returns `{ data: ... }` or `{ error: ... }`. So you can write your own function that calls your normal baseQuery with all arguments, and then add extra logic with the result of that before finally returning an error or data.